# Is it possible to load neural network weights onto a new model with the same architecture, but of different size, in Keras? If so, how?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

For example if you have weights from a convolutional neural net layer of filter size 64x64, and you want to load these pre-trained weights onto a new convolutional neural net layer of different size (say 32x32 or 128x128), how can this be achieved?  Can you transform (oversample, undersample, repeat, average, interpolate, truncate, etc.) the weights to fit onto any size layer?

Are there examples of this in Keras?

Are there best practices?

Comment: You can but that is not commonly done so I don't think there are examples, you would still have to retrain the network.

Comment: Do you mean the shape of the filters. So input image sizes of 64x64. Or do you mean just more filters in a layer?

Comment: The former--different shape of the filters.  It's fine if the model is re-trained, but at least it has some extent of pre-trained weights to initialize the next larger (or smaller) model.

Comment: But do your filter have really size of 64x64 or it's the output map size?